# "cgi-bin" directory for Apache not found on windows 7

Tags: apache, perl, tomcat

I tried to install Tomcat Apache versions 6 and 7. and Was fairly Successful.
Now, im using this to try by perl cgi scripts written. but When i see inside the folder "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0" or "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0" i dont see the cgi bin folder. 
Also the https.conf file is missing.
I understand we have to write our scripts in the folder ( eg: test.cgi ).
Could someone please guide me?

Im trying to build a web page using perl cgi scripts.

Thank you and Good day.
-S.K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy CGI in tomcat, remove commands for following lines in web.xml found in {tomcat dir}/conf.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cgi</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>debug</param-name>
      <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cgiPathPrefix</param-name>
      <param-value>WEB-INF/cgi</param-value>
    </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Then deploy all your cgi's in WEB-INF/cgi in your web project. Then start tomcat.
Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use perl/cgi why are you using tomcat? Tomcat is best suited if you want a lightweight and free servlet container. But if you must, find more info on enabling CGI here:

- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cgi-howto.html
- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cgi-howto.html

You should rather look at Apache HTTP Server if you don't have Java (JSP/Servlets)
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html